# Disable Redirect in Auth::attempt() Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, authentication

I create REST API using Laravel. And i am is in Login API, so i use AuthController built it from Laravel.

But, when i authenticate user login using `Auth::attempt()` in the first time i successfully get User Info cause i call this method `Auth::user()`.
But, when i run again in second time, i get this following Error :

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

I know it send redirect automatically if user has authenticated. And save the session.

Here is my Login Code in `AuthController.php`

```
public function demo() {

        if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('email','password'))) {
            return Auth::user();
        } else {
            return "false";
        }
    }
```

And i write the routes like this :

```
Route::post('demo', 'Auth\AuthController@demo');
```

How to disable redirect in that case?
Cause i wanna call my API from my mobile application.

Thank you

Comment: seems that redirect is fired by a middleware, check your middleware configuration

Comment: I am not use any middleware.

Comment: pls share a piece of code where you try to authentificate the user - Auth::attempt() does not do any redirects, only returns true/false. And also if possible, route you are trying to access. Maybe you put it under guest access - so after authorizing user it is redirected out of guest-allowed routes.

Comment: @Silwerclaw Please check my questios. I add some codes. Thank you

Comment: if you didn't change your AuthController from default - so there is a call to redirect on guest access in constructor $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Answer**
>
> Okay i get the solution, but it's not elegant way. I edit the class
>   `RedirectIfAuthenticated` and remove `return redirect(/home)` in
>   `handle` method.